# What is the inverse of X modulo $1 + X + X^2 + X^3 + X^4$?

Tags: ring-theory, inverse, irreducible-polynomials

What is the inverse of X modulo $1 + X + X^2 + X^3 + X^4$?
Is there any open softwares to calculate such things easily?

Comment: **Hint** $\bmod\, 1+xf\!:\, \ (-f)x\equiv 1\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $1+X+X^2+X^3+X^4=1+X(1+X+X^2+X^3)$.

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much :)